# Reverse geocoding with postgis in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, postgis

In my model, I have created column address and start_point. start_point is stored in st_point datatype from PostGIS.

I have found one of the methods to get the address from longitude and latitude, but I haven't found any method to get addresses from st_point datatype.

```
# app/models/place.rb
reverse_geocoded_by :latitude, :longitude,
  :address => :location
after_validation :reverse_geocode
```

How can I do reverse geocoding by using st_point datatype from PostGIS in my application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can manually define `:latitude` & `:longitude` manually like this

```
# app/models/place.rb
reverse_geocoded_by :latitude, :longitude
after_validation :reverse_geocode

attr_reader :latitude, :longitude

def latitude
  start_point.lat if start_point
end

def longitude
  start_point.lon if start_point
end
```

And remember st_point is defined as `POINT(lon lat)` as per the Cartesian plane expression (x,y). As oppose to the lat/lon format we usually see on Google Maps.